# Same address looks capitalized and lowercased when using web3.eth.getAccounts and eth_requestAccounts

Tags: ethereum, metamask

I'm using Metamask as `ethereum` provider in dapp

When I'm calling `web3.eth.getAccounts()`

It returns `0xaBCd12baabcd7be123B6123DabCD484321ABcd3`

When i'm sending `ethereum.send("eth_requestAccounts")`

It returns same address but chars are lower cased or capitalized based on some weird logic `0xabcD12BAAbcd7BE123b6123Dabcd484321abCD3`.

There's no other change to the address rather than that, no digit is missing and order is correct.

Why wuold that be happening?